# How to change add to cart css classes commerce

Tags: commerce, bootstrap-theme

I'd like to remove all .btn classes on my commerce add to cart-forms as the design dictates text-based links and not buttons. 
But I can't find the relevant markup in any of the template files.

It's a D7 site running the latest versions of everything. Theme is Bootstrap, and the add to cart forms are presented via a Viewfield allowing for an Add To Cart-form per variation on the Product Display.

Cheers,

Comment: They're set in `bootstrap_preprocess_button`, in templates/system/button.vars.inc

Comment: Thanks @Clive. I'm just beginning to learn PHP so sorry if I'm missing anything - but I don't see where I can remove the btn in the add to cart-form from that file?